# Split string if match from one of the item from array

Tags: javascript

How can i split the string if the value that match from one the item from array? I'm getting this value from selected field:

```
elegant-themes-line-icons-map-pin
```

and i want to split like:

`['elegant-themes-line-icons', 'map-pin']` or `['font-awesome', 'removed']`

I have a lists of fronts in array like:

```
['elegant-themes-line-icons', 'font-awesome', 'simple-line-icons']
```

and the value should always `fontname-iconname` and i need to split that value like the code above and i like the condition something like this:

```
function onChange(value) {
// example the selected value is 'font-awesome-facebook-alt'
if ( value has font string like font-awesome ) {
   var icons = ['font-awesome', 'facebook-alt'];
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could find the right starting string and slice for the right side.

```js
var list = ['elegant-themes-line-icons', 'font-awesome', 'simple-line-icons'],
    values = ['elegant-themes-line-icons-map-pin', 'font-awesome-removed', 'foo-bar-baz'],
    result = values.map(s => {
        var left = list.find(l => s.startsWith(l)) || '',
            right = left ? s.slice(left.length + 1) : s;
        return [left, right];
    });

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Wow, you made my day. but can you please update the code so the "-" will be removed before the icon name. Thank you so much!

Comment: please see edit.

Comment: You really helped me, i appreciate that answer. Thank you!